# Speech to Text Azure from AudioSource data Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, speech-to-text, azure-speech

I would like to use Speech to Text Azure services to translate the AudioSource object's audio (clip). How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

With the information you have provided, I am assuming that you would like capture the output of the  AudioSource Object and send it to the Azure Services for translation.

For custom Audio Source Configuration - You could use the [PullAudioInputStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.pushaudioinputstream?view=azure-dotnet)/[PushAudioInputStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.pushaudiooutputstream?view=azure-dotnet) . In this case you will have to intercept the output audio - send it to the SDK - inturn to the azure services.

Came across these posts which you could use it as reference :

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/95
- [Custom audio input bytes to azure cognitive speech translation service in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300431/custom-audio-input-bytes-to-azure-cognitive-speech-translation-service-in-python)

****Or****

You could use the SDK for unity

The sample here walks you through

- Speech recognition with translation in multiple languages simultaneously.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/unity/speechrecognizer

Answer (score 0):

From the current Speech SDK samples, I would recommend you to look first following sample

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/unity/from-unitymicrophone

Which use AudioSource with Unity microphone. What you would need to do is to modify the microphone part to read from the file instead and replace SpeechRecognizer with TranslationRecognizer.

We will work for more samples in future, let us know if this helps.